# Socket.io unable to listen on in-app browser of fb and insta

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, socket.io, google-oauth, passport.js

We are trying to authenticate with Express using passport.js with React on the Front-End.

We are following this for reference.

https://codeburst.io/react-authentication-with-twitter-google-facebook-and-github-862d59583105

Here we are passing the socket id in the new window using window.open and listening to this io event on first window.

```
    openPopup() {
        const { provider, socket } = this.props
        const width = 600, height = 600
        const left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (width / 2)
        const top = (window.innerHeight / 2) - (height / 2)
        const url = `${API_URL}/${provider}?socketId=${socket.id}`
    
        return window.open(url, '',       
          `toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, 
          scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=${width}, 
          height=${height}, top=${top}, left=${left}`
        )
      }
```

This works perfectly fine on desktop and mobile browsers. But it's not working on in-app browser as window.open is not opening a new window.

How do we use socket.io in such a case either via a popup or redirect?. Please help been stuck on this for quite a while now.